# buff.getInt() & 0xffffffffL is an identity?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bytebuffer

Here is some code I have been looking at:

```
public static long getUnsignedInt(ByteBuffer buff) {
    return (long) (buff.getInt() & 0xffffffffL);
}
```

Is there any reason to do `buff.getInt() & 0xffffffffL` (`0xffffffffL` has 32 bits of 1's in the 32 least significant bits)? It looks to me like the result will always be `buff.getInt()`.

Comment: I think the name of the method provides a clue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, it's because the method needs to convert a *signed* `int` (which all Java `int`s are) to an *unsigned* quantity.

If you were to just do `(long) buff.getInt()`, and `buff.getInt()` returned `-1`, you'd end up with `-1`. And that's a signed quantity -- not what the method is supposed to return.

So what the method does is forces `buff.getInt()` to become unsigned by ANDing the `int` bits with `0x00000000FFFFFFFF`. This effectively "reinterprets" the bits of the signed `int` as an unsigned `int` (really a signed `long`, but as only the lower 32 bits are ever going to be set, it works as an unsigned `int`), producing the desired result.

For example, (working with bytes for brevity).

Say `buff.getInt()` is really `buff.getByte()`, and returns `-1 == 0xFF`

Try to cast that to an `int`, you'll end up with `0xFFFFFFFF` -- still `-1`, due to the magic of sign extension.

However, mask that with `0xFF`, and you'll end up with `0x000000FF` == 255 -- the desired value.

I *believe* the explicit cast is unnecessary (it isn't on my machine), but I could be missing something...

---

Edit: Turns out the cast actually *is* unnecessary. From JLS section 5.6.2:

Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:

- If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
- Otherwise,if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

Comment: @user3580294 Rest assured, your assumption the cast being not necessary is spot on. Using a long literal (0x0...FL) for the masking value already turns the expressions type to long.

Comment: @Durandal Is it because `buff.getInt()` is implicitly cast to `long` in `buff.getInt() & 0xffffffffL`?

Comment: @user3662937 Yep, see my edit. The behavior is specified in the JLS.

Answer (score 4):

If `buff.getInt()` is a negative number, it will still be a negative number when casting it to a long. But it'll be sign extended.

So, if you want to preserve the bit pattern, e.g. to try to interpret the values as unsigned values, `&0xffffffffL` will mask off those bits.

e.g. if buff.getInt() returns -2147483648, the returned int will have a bit pattern of 0x80000000. Cast  to long, that'll still be -2147483648 , but with a bit pattern of 0xffffffff80000000. `0xffffffff80000000 & 0xFFFFFFFF` preserves the original bit pattern of 0x80000000

Answer (score 2):

Integers in Java (`int` and `long`) are signed, [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) numbers. That means the high digit is 0 if the number is positive (or 0), and -1 if it's negative.

To convert from an `int` to a `long`, Java uses sign extension. This means that the numbers it "fills in" to the left depend on that leftmost digit. To illustrate with going from 4-bit to 8-bit numbers:

- 1 = 0001 -> 0000 0001
- -1 = 1111 -> 1111 1111

So if you want to interpret `1111` as a signed number (ie, 15), you can't just convert it from 4 bits to 8: you'd get `1111 1111`, which is -1. What you want is `0000 1111`, which is 15.

To do this, you need to do a bitwise AND on the number to mask out the high bits which have been filled in, and turn those into 0's.